# Using xmlpullparser, how to get dataset namespace value

Tags: android, parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm parsing xml that starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset
  xmlns:perinote="urn:perinote.com/perinote-1.2" >
...
```

And I'm wondering how I read the value for the "xmlns:perinote" tag. From there I want to be able to handle multiple versions.

I tried

```
String nameSpace = parser.getAttributeValue (null, "xmlns:perinote");
```

but it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind. I think this is the correct solution:

```
String nameSpace = parser.getNamespaceUri (0);
```

As long as this is done immediately after parsing the "dataset" tag, I think it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
String namespace = parser.getNamespace("perinote");
String attrValue = parser.getAttributeValue(namespace, "attributeName");
```